# Pushing dummy data to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, github, server

I build my app with Ruby on Rails, right now I push it to GitHub and then to server. I have my app working on the server and then I upload few images and some dummy data from the front-page. During the second push to GitHub, my images are being deleted from the server. What folder should I ommit and how to do it? Should I use GitIgnore? to keep uploaded data by future users of the app, and still being able to update the app through GitHub.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Are you using Capistrano to deploy and update your code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use ActiveStorage? In that case, you should use a cloud storage provider like AWS or Google Cloud Storage.

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The thing is I do not use active storage right now.

Comment: I currently use gems like: carrierwave and minimagick.

Comment: I also want to connect to DigitalOcean Spaces, which is alternative to S3 Amazon bucket.